# Opening various main.py files in Eclipse without creating a new project

Tags: python, eclipse

I have a python project developed in eclipse. Independantly there are various data directories in various locations and it is desirable to operate on each with a different `main.py` that imports the python project. If I store a `main.py` with my data, **how can I open it in eclipse and run the debugger?**

I can run ipython in each directory without a problem; but, I am not clear on how to move between different `main.py` files within eclipse. The run configuration does allow you to go outside the project and **I would prefer not having to change this each time** anyway. Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting up each main.py + data directory as its own Eclipse project, each with a custom run/debug configuration.  You do have extra projects, but they don't require any ongoing maintenance.

After the initial setup, you continue work on the real python project and debugging any given data directory consists of selecting the appropriate project and invoking the debugger.  Not maximally elegant, but not bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly loath to make new projects, you could bring the `main.py` files into the project and store the location of the associated data directory inside each of them.  Each main begins by changing to the data directory, and then runs as usual.  In eclipse you set up multiple run configurations, one for each `main.py` which you can then run without any extra tinkering.

It is inelegant and fragile to keep the data directory information inside each `main.py`, but maybe better for your purposes.